# JQuery Mobile exception when re-adding dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi (I may not be doing this correctly) - I am trying to and having problems navigating to a page in my JQuery Mobile (JQM) application when trying to load the page as a dialog using "changePage()". I have looked around and have tried a few alternatives with no luck :(

E.g. I have a login page that opens successfully as a dialog on the application init:

```
$.mobile.changePage(page, {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog' });
```

the login screen has a login button, which when clocked forwards to a normal (non dialog) page, again successfully and again using changePage:

```
$.mobile.changePage( page );
```

The problem occurs when I again try to load the login page in the dialog (e.g. when logging out). I have a logout button, which when clicked navigates back to the login page:

```
$.mobile.changePage(page, {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog' });
```

However this time I get the following exception in the JQM lib: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined"

Here is some example code that recreates the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function()  {
    createPage("login");
});

function createPage( pageStr ) {  
    var page = $("<div id='pageWrapper' class='pageWrapper' data-role='page' ></div>");
    var header = createHeader( pageStr );
    var content = createContent( pageStr );

    page.append(header, content);

    $("body").append( page );

    if(pageStr == "login") {     
        $.mobile.changePage(page, {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog' }); 
    }
    else {
        $.mobile.changePage( page );
    }
}

function createHeader( pageStr ) {
    var headerContainer = $("<div id='header' class='header' data-role='header' data-position='fixed'></div>");

    if(pageStr != "login") {
        var logOutButton = $("<a onclick='logout()' class='ui-btn-right' data-rel='dialog'>Logout</a>");
        headerContainer.append(logOutButton);
    }

    var headerTitle = $("<h1>Page: " + pageStr + "</h1>");
    headerContainer.append(headerTitle);
    return headerContainer;
}

function createContent( pageStr ) {
    var contentDiv = $("<div id='content' class='content' data-role='content'></div>");
    var contentBuilder = $("<div></div>");

    if(pageStr == "login") {
        contentBuilder.append(createloginForm());
    }
    else {
        contentBuilder.append(createWrapper());
    }
    contentDiv.append(contentBuilder);
    return contentDiv;
}

function createloginForm() {
    var form = $("<form id='loginForm' method='post'></form>");
    var loginButton = $("<p><input type='button' value='Login' onclick='login()'></input></p>");
    form.append(loginButton);
    return form;
}

function createWrapper() {
    var tmpText = $("<h2>some content ...</h2>");
    return tmpText;
}

function login() {
    createPage("main")
}

function logout() {
    createPage("login"); // pages[0] = login page
}

</script>
```

Thanks,
Jon.

Comment: is it possible that you're trying to create a duplicate div element on page with the same ID on logout?

Comment: What I have not included in this example is that I also clean the page / divs (removing any existing elements) so I dont think so... I will double check this though.

Comment: I guess that could be a problem as well - if you first create a page using JQM, then remove it outside JQM manually and try to create the same page once again - the old page would not exists in DOM, so I'd guess JQM will try to search for it internally and fail with out of bounds on an indexOf() call

Comment: I gut the same issue when not removing the page as well :(

Comment: Both the origin page (login) and target page (main) have the same id (pageWrapper), which could explain your problem changing page. Did you try modifying this id according to the page so that you do not have a duplicate ?

Comment: @Romain - Yes I tried this, but it made no difference. E.g. changing the od to "loginWrpaper" when the page string is set to "login" etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the comment - I did not mention / include in the example, that I am cleaning the pages each time therefore no duplicate elements or ids are being added (only one page is added / rendered at any one time).

I think I have fixed the problem by manually initialising the page before hanging it - not sure if its a "cosier"  fix, but appears to work:

Before calling the changePage() method, I need to first initialize the new page: E.mobile.initializePage();

Thanks again,
Jon.